# Can the PowerEdge 2420 24U Rack Enclosure Be Completely Disassembled?

Tags: dell-poweredge, rack

We have to relocate our existing Dell PowerEdge 2420 24U Rack Enclosure to another room in our office.

Unfortunately, the door (to the new room) is too small for the Dell rack enclosure to fit through.

Can the Dell rack enclosure be completely disassembled?

Comment: Hmm... Measure twice, cut once... as my carpenter friend would say

Comment: You probably don't need to disassemble it completely; picture the turn-in-the-doorhole thing furniture movers do.

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell for sure from the pictures on the Dell site, but all the racks I've worked with can - in theory - be taken apart.

The doors and side panels come off easily, then the rack consists of a top piece, a bottom piece with wheels or feet attached, and four corner posts.  Looking at our Compaq racks (which look similar to the pics of the Dell), there are big, countersunk-headed bolts holding the posts to the base and top.  The reason I say "in theory" is that I think it would take an impact wrench to loosen the bolts on our racks, they're *tight*.